# Semantic UI: How to define selected item of search dropdown ("<select>")?

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

how can I set the selected item of a search dropdown (select) form field? I tried it with the following jQuery/JavaScript code:

```
if (equal == 0) {
    $('#sj_company').html($('#sj_company').html() + '<option value="' + key + '" selected="selected">' + data[key] + '</option>');
    $('.searchdropdown').dropdown('set selected', data[key]);
} else {
    $('#sj_company').html($('#sj_company').html() + '<option value="' + key + '">' + data[key] + '</option>');
}
```

Edit:
The base is the semantic ui frontend framework ;-)

Comment: No that also not working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake was: I have initialized the Semantic UI Dropdown **before** I've loaded the dropdown items via AJAX. The solution: Initialize the Dropdown **AFTER** the AJAX loading process.

Comment: Great that it solves your problem but that isn't always possible, as there are use cases where the values need to be set later.

Answer (score 32):

For the Semantic UI framework, you should consult the guide here: [dropdown behavior](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#behavior). That tells us to make the following call:

`$('#dropdown').dropdown('set selected', value);`

Or pass an object (perhaps useful for multiple select or to the developer's preference):

`$('#dropdown').dropdown({'set selected': value});`

**Non-framework answer (before question was edited for specific framework)**

If the select list has an id of say `dropdown`, you can do:

`$('#dropdown').val();`

To set the value, say the option has a value of `a`, you can do:

`$('#dropdown').val('a');`

I suggest reading the jQuery page on [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vo9kpsry/1

Comment: I don't want to get the value, I want to set it!

Comment: @AntonDachauer Ah, okay -- I updated the answer. You can pass the `value` to the `val` call to set it -- like `$('#dropdown').val('a');`.

Comment: No, not with Semantic UI (Not with Semantic UI (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)

Comment: @AntonDachauer I've updated with the answer for Semantic UI. In the future, if you are not using standard DOM/HTML/JavaScript, you should state that up front.

Comment: I'm talking about an Semantic UI Dropdown (Semantic UI is a frontend framework). It's based on a HTML select, that's true.

Comment: @AntonDachauer Which is completely unrelated to the question -- there is no way to know that is the problem based on the details in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80204/discussion-between-anton-dachauer-and-cymen).

Comment: @AntonDachauer No need! I don't have anything else to add. I'm glad you figured out your problem.

Comment: The right behaviour format is $('#dropdown').dropdown('set selected', value);

Comment: @praisegeek I suspect you can also pass the an object with multiple key-values to handle multiple selects. I like passing the object even for one.

Comment: @praisegeek But I updated the answer as it is a valid point! Thanks.

Comment: For a multiple selection dropdown, I was able to select multiple items by making successive calls.  For example,  $('#dropdown').dropdown('set selected', 'value_1') followed by  $('#dropdown').dropdown('set selected', 'value_2')

Comment: @kmxr does it also work to do  $('#dropdown').dropdown('set selected', ['value_1', 'value_2']) -- just curious if it accepts an array for value?

Comment: @Cymen Yes, an array  ['value_1', 'value_2'] does work.  It is cumulative so, to reset you will need to  $('#dropdown').dropdown('clear')

Answer (score 16):

You can simply set the default value by set hidden value input which is exist with semanic dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="countries" value="tf">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="default text">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="tf"><i class="tf flag"></i>French Territories</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="ga"><i class="ga flag"></i>Gabon</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="gm"><i class="gm flag"></i>Gambia</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe too late but someone may need it

Answer (score 3):

### fomantic-ui

Update answer to ([fomantic-ui](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)) (The official community fork of the popular Semantic-UI framework). **Semantic-UI not maintain since 2018.

Examples: Two option (cat, dog) select dog by deafult.

#### Option 1 - By hidden input

`<input type="hidden" name="type" value="dog">`

> Selection dropdowns can be initialized directly on a select or with
> the matching HTML and a hidden input.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui dropdown selection">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="dog">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Animal</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="cat">Cat</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="dog">Dog</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

#### Option 2 by `set selected` API

```
set selected(value,$selectedItem,preventChangeTrigger)
```

Sets value as selected.

https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#behavior

```js
  let initial_state = "dog";
  $('.dropdown')
    .dropdown('set selected', initial_state);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="pet">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Cat</div>
  <div class="scrollhint menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="cat">Cat</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="dog">Dog</div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

### Option 3 - Initializing with Javascript only

https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#initializing-with-javascript-only

`selected : true`

```js
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
    values: [
      {
        name: 'cat',
        value: 'cat'
      },
      {
        name     : 'dog',
        value    : 'dog',
        selected : true
      }
    ]
  })
;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui selection dropdown">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

#### Option 4 by option `selected` attribute

Not API option.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="ui selection dropdown">
    <option class="item" data-value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option class="item" data-value="dog" selected>Dog</option>
</select >


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.8/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```